# VBA Issue with inserting images when the image changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro to insert an image to my excel file with a specified file path. However, when the image changes (file path stays the same), and I run the macro, when I close the excel and open it again, all the previous images would change to the current image. How can I make it such that when I insert the image, the image will not change on excel?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVAWU.png)

Before I press save and leave the excel however, it works fine.

Comment: Please don't paste images of code - you can copy and paste the code as text into your question.

Comment: Have a hidden sheet with the information needed to save and load the images when the spreadsheet opens or closes.

Comment: You need to post your code as text if you want any help with this problem

Comment: There's an Edit button at the bottom of your post below the Excel & VBA tags so you can add the code as text - paste the code, highlight it and then press the `{ }` button to format it.